# When is Perl's scalar comma operator useful?

Tags: perl, operators, comma-operator

Is there any reason to use a scalar comma operator anywhere other than in a `for` loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the Perl scalar comma is a "port" of the C comma operator, [these comments](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4db.html) are probably apropos:

> Once in a while, you find yourself in
>   a situation in which C expects a
>   single expression, but you have two
>   things you want to say. The most
>   common (and in fact the only common)
>   example is in a `for` loop, specifically
>   the first and third controlling
>   expressions. What if (for example) you
>   want to have a loop in which `i` counts
>   up from `0` to `10` at the same time that
>   `j` is counting down from `10` to `0`?

So, your instinct that it's mainly useful in `for` loops is a good one, I think.

Answer (score 3):

I occasionally use it in the conditional (sometimes erroneously called "the ternary") operator, if the code is easier to read than breaking it out into a real if/else:

```
my $blah = condition() ? do_this(), do_that() : do_the_other_thing();
```

It could also be used in some expression where the last result is important, such as in a `grep` expression, but in this case it's just the same as if a semicolon was used:

```
my @results = grep { setup(), condition() } @list;
```

Comment: Isn't the "?:" operator ternary ? :)

Comment: @eugene: it's *a* ternary operator, but it's not correct to call it *the* ternary operator.